# Erlang API for a NoSql DB running on Windows

Tags: windows, api, erlang, couchdb, berkeley-db

I'm running Windows and I want to control a NoSql DB (Berkeley or CouchDB) from an Erlang program.

Has anyone done it? I really can't find any example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CouchDB is controlled via HTTP (REST, specifically) so not only does it not matter if you are running Windows, but it doesn't even matter that you're running Erlang. You need no special tools or drivers in order to make HTTP requests from Erlang to CouchDB. The CouchDB documentation is very clear on how to interact with CouchDB via REST.

If you want to communicate via Erlang messages, check out couchbeam: https://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam. As you might know, CouchDB is written in Erlang, so you can interact with it by sending it Erlang messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try it, but I should have been more precise: "I want to control" <=> My application needs to make use of several (or even tens of) thousands simple writes per second. As it is a desktop application, I'm concerned about performance and delays from the network part, HTTP calls, etc. Is there a way to communicate with a DB directly via erlang? 
Or maybe another DB would be a better approach in this case?

Comment: Ok, I've read it, but I was thinking about sth like [https://github.com/jchris/hovercraft](https://github.com/jchris/hovercraft) . Thanks anyway, I'm using couchbeam.